# How to bind a List's size property to a Node's disabled property?

Tags: javafx, arraylist, observable

Suppose I have an `ObservableList` and a `Button` in the same controller class:

```
private ObservableList<NameItem> _selectedList = _database.getONameList();

@FXML
private Button nextButton;
```

How do I make it so that the `Button` is only enabled while the `ObservableList` is not empty? Is there a binding property I can use to set this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily with just a couple of simple Bindings, actually.

First, you want to create an `IntegerBinding` that is bound to the size of your `ObservableList`:

```
IntegerBinding listSize = Bindings.size(_selectedList);
```

Then create a new `BooleanBinding` that is bound to whether or not the `listSize` binding is greater than 0:

```
BooleanBinding listPopulated = listSize.greaterThan(0);
```

Now, all you need to do is bind the button's `disableProperty` to the opposite of the `listPopulated` property using the `not()` method (since `listPopulated` will be `true` if items are in the list, you want to actually pass `false` to the button's `disableProperty`):

```
button.disableProperty().bind(listPopulated.not());
```

Here is a quick MCVE to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.IntegerBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create an empty ObservableList
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Create a binding to extract the list's size to a property
        IntegerBinding listSizeProperty = Bindings.size(list);

        // Create a boolean binding that will return true only if the list has 1 or more elements
        BooleanBinding listPopulatedProperty = listSizeProperty.greaterThan(0);

        // Create the button we want to enable/disable
        Button button = new Button("Submit");

        // Bind the button's disableProperty to the opposite of the listPopulateProperty
        // If listPopulateProperty is false, the button will be disabled, and vice versa
        button.disableProperty().bind(listPopulatedProperty.not());

        // Create another button to add an item to the list, just to demonstrate the concept
        Button btnAddItem = new Button("Add Item");
        btnAddItem.setOnAction(event -> {
            list.add("New Item");
            System.out.println(list.size());
        });

        // Add the buttons to the layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(btnAddItem, button);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

In the above example, the "Submit" button is disabled until you add an item to the `ObservableList` using the "Add Item" button.

**EDIT:** As Lukas excellently points out in the comments below, these Bindings can also all be chained together to simplify things (either method is equally valid; it just depends on which you find more readable, really):

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(list).greaterThan(0).not())
```

---

> **Another Method**

Another way to do this is with a `ListChangeListener` that enables or disables the button any time the list changes:

```
    list.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) c -> {
        // If the size of the list is less than 1, disable the button; otherwise enable it
        button.setDisable(c.getList().size() < 1);
    });
```

This will essentially do exactly the same thing as the first method, but you'll need to set the initial state of the button yourself before the listener can keep it updated for you.

Comment: Nice and very detailed answer, however you may add an example where all the binding calls are chained: `button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(list).greaterThan(0).not())`

Comment: Excellent point, @LukasKörfer. I have added that to the answer too. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Just to note, since the goal is to disable a `Button` when the `ObservableList` is empty, another option is to bind the `disableProperty` directly to the result of [`Bindings.isEmpty(ObservableList)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty(javafx.collections.ObservableList)).

Comment: Thank you, @Slaw. I feel my answer is absolute overkill now :). I never actually noticed the `isEmpty()` method...

Comment: Regarding the title of the question, your answer is no overkill, because it works for any size constraint ;)